# PHP new COM("word.application") SaveAS causes "Disk is Full" Error

Tags: php, windows, com, ms-word

I have a PHP script running on XAMPP in Windows XP that will open a .doc file and then save it as a different copy. This was working fine earlier on, but out of nowhere the error message keeps appearing.

```
$path = "c:/xampp/htdocs/";
com_load_typelib('Word.Application');
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");

$word->Documents->Open($path."tmp/invoice.doc");

$bookmarkname = "InvoiceNo";
$objBookmark  = $word->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($bookmarkname)->Range->Text = "INVOICE ID";

$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($path."tmp/invoice2.doc");
$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
$word = null;
```

I feel that the code is not the problem, as it was working a few hours ago, but now isnt. I suspect it is something to do with my Word 2003, prehaps somethings caused it to bug out.

I have tried rebooting, clearing temp folder as described on the Microsoft website.

I can still write to the folder by using file_put_contents, so MAYBE if I could extract the raw data from the $word->Documents[1] then I could use file_put_contents to save it instead of using Word's save function. The problem is that this is quite poorly documented so I cant find a list of available functions available to me to do that.

Comment: What's $path? Is it perhaps a network share that's acting up or you don't have control over and lost write privileges to?

Comment: sorry, thats in my config file. I have edited the file now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I have solved the problem myself.

I've saved it at a RTF, then used this class to convert it back into .doc format, seems to take alot longer but has solved the problem, thank god.

Link: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/1256.html

Thanks everyone for looking anyway.
Jamie